How to show components only for some screens?
I want to show specific Header and AppBar only for some pages. I do next:
import { DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import { Stack } from 'expo-router'
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import 'react-native-reanimated'
import routes from '@/constants/routes'
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme'
import AppBar from '@/components/AppBar'
import Header from '@/components/Header'
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { mainStyles } from '@/styles/main'
import { usePathname } from 'expo-router'

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() // Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete

export default function RootLayout() {
  const pathname = usePathname()

  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync()
    }
  }, [loaded])

  if (!loaded) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DefaultTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={mainStyles.wrapper}>
          {pathname !== routes.settings.link && <Header/>}
          <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name={routes.index.name} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name={routes.alphabet.name} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name={routes.colors.name} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name={routes.animals.name} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name={routes.settings.name} options={{ headerShown: true }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" options={{ headerShown: true }}/>
          </Stack>
          {pathname !== routes.settings.link && <AppBar/>}
          <StatusBar style="auto" hidden/>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

I don't know I can put Header and AppBar just in _layout.tsx and use conditional rendering for my components near to Stack. Is it correct way? Or will be better add my components inside pages?

What is your goal? Another option is to create a subfolder with its own _layout.tsx that has the header similar to how you mentioned. The views within that subfolder would then have the header. I would avoid overly using conditionals to display a header. It can be confusing from a design perspective.

@knary goal is don't repeat myself. If it's a component for many pages - use once. Need exclusion? Use condition. Thank you for your answer!
